DirectoryInfo on Simulated file system
I realy like DirectoryInfo class that C# provides
I use it to create, delete, list files like this
using System.io;
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        String path = @"D:\MyTestFile1.txt";  
        DirectoryInfo fl = new DirectoryInfo(path);  
        fl.Create();

        Console.WriteLine(di.GetDirectories())
    }
}


Now is it possible for this class to work on simulated file system (in this case directoryTree in text file, nothing fancy, infact the only methods that I would need to extend are GetDirectories() and GetFiles())
lets imagine we would feed DirectoryInfo with a text file containing our file system
D:\file1.txt
D:\file2.py
D:\ourFolder\lion.mp4
D:\ourFolder\anotherfolder\imaginara.jpg
D:\file3.png
D:\file4.jpg

is it possible to extend DirectoryInfo somehow so we could feed it our simulated file system?
Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Maybe look at Mocking it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159661/how-to-mock-directoryinfo-class

thnx, but I didn't intend to test this class, just liked functionality that DirectoryInfo provided and thought I could get the same functionality for my directory tree in txt file), maybe there is some similar class that would do the same as DirectoryInfo would but on directory tree in txt file?

You could always implement something on top of https://github.com/TestableIO/System.IO.Abstractions
