# Mocking IO operations in Nunit using Typemock

Tags: c#, nunit, typemock, typemock-isolator, nunit-2.5.9

I have the following method.

```
public string CreateFile(string path, string fileName)
{
    string fullPath = path + "ExportedFiles\\";
    if (Directory.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
    }
    string filePath = fullPath + fileName;
    return filePath;
}
```

I attempted to used the following in my test case.

```
[Test, Isolated] 
public void TestCreateFileIfPathExists() 
{ 
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => System.IO.Directory.Exists("gsgs")).WillReturn(true);
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => testMyClass.CreateFile(@"D:\testFolder\","TestFile")).CallOriginal(); 
    string result = testMyClass.CreateFile(@"D:\testFolder\", "TestFile");
    Assert.AreEqual("D:\\testFolder\\ExportedFiles\\TestFile", result);
}
```

It's throwing the following typemock exception.

> TypeMock.TypeMockException : 
>   *** No method calls found in recording block. Please check:  * Are you trying to fake a field instead of a property?  * Are you are trying to fake an unsupported mscorlib type?

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you mock out the file system in C# for unit testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087351/how-do-you-mock-out-the-file-system-in-c-sharp-for-unit-testing)

Comment: but they haven't mentioned how to achieve this using Typemock

Comment: Can you share the code for your entire unit test?

Comment: Please always add additional information or clarifications to your questions in the question itself rather than in the comments. This will help future users/viewers understand the question.

Comment: @RyanGates: edited as per your comment

Comment: Please always copy the entire error message(even if it includes parts you don't consider relevant).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the last question of the exception that you are getting,

> * Are you are trying to fake an unsupported mscorlib type?

there is actually a web address after that in the exception, which reads

> See supported types here: http://www.typemock.com/mscorlib-types

When you go there, you will notice:

[image]

Notably absent from this list is the [`System.IO.Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) class, which appears to not be supported [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) as of this writing. This is the line that is causing your error.

Comment: @user2435880 The only way that I am aware of is to create a layer of abstraction between your code and the code that goes to disk like in the [How do you mock out the file system in C# for unit testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087351) question.