# Mocking filesystem

Tags: .net, unit-testing, typemock

If my unit tests rely on the file system and I need to mock this, what is the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: If you're actually talking about Typemock you shouldn't have an issue as Typemock can mock any type, including sealed types.

Comment: Chanting "your filesystem is worthless and weak" is a good way to mock them...

Comment: I thought thatTypemock couldn't mock things in mscorlib, which a lot of this is in.  Except maybe DateTime.Now.  Maybe.

Comment: @Sam - You're correct. TypeMock cannot mock objects in mscrolib, but they did find a way to mock DateTime during the research into the Racer product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have two options: eiter abstract all file-system related logic behind a `IFileSystemService`, or use [Stubs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/stubs/) from Microsoft, which is

> ...a lightweight framework for .NET that provides test stubs. For interfaces and non-sealed classes, type-safe wrappers are generated that can be easily customized by attaching delegates.

Answer (score 9):

The file system is an excellent example of how TDD can drive you towards a better, more flexible design. Often, when you interact with the file system, you can deal with reading and writing files using **Streams** or **TextWriters** instead of actual files.

These are all abstract types and so are easy to mock.

Now you have a more flexible API because it's not tightly coupled to the file system, but still supports file operations.

Comment: +1, using streams is great because you stay compatible with all sorts of input/output devices.

Answer (score 1):

This [Needed: File system interfaces and implementation in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664277/needed-file-system-interfaces-and-implementation-in-net) might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer I work at Typemock.

I'm glad to say, that our last versions support the following types of System.IO to be mocked:

- File
- Directory
- FileStream

There is a short example:

```
public void Test()
{
    string path = @"C:\TypemockCan.txt";

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => File.Exists(null)).WillReturn(true);

    Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(path));
}
```

See more [examples](http://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fmocking.htm).